# run time thread creation

Tags: c, multithreading

At run time, how can I create a thread ?

I will take # of thread from standard input--terminal-- then I will create thread according to this number. But, How ?

```
Ex: 
   input : N,                N is integer 

   in main function 

                create N thread
```

EDIT : platform Linux

Comment: Yes, you can. But exactly how to do it depends very much on which system you are using to run this. Threads are not part of the C standard. Which system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, threads (if we assume that we are using pthreads) are created with the call **pthread_create**, and you can call that from a loop.

Here is the start of a C function that creates N threads:

```
int start_N_threads(int N) {
    pthread_t threads[N];
    printf("Starting %d thread(s)...\n", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_body, (void*)&results[i]) != 0) {
            printf("Couldn't create thread %d.\n", i);
        }
    }
    printf("The %d thread(s) are running.\n", N);
```